# java.lang.IllegalStateException: BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath) must not be null

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an error which is answered by so many people but yet I feel my problem is little unique.

**Problem is**
I am clicking an picture direct from the camera and converting that image to bitmap with using the below line of code.This line of code is getting executing in the **onStart**.

```
    val bitmap: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath)
```

**How I am getting this photoPath is explained below**

```
 private val photoPath: String? by lazy {
    arguments?.getString(ARG_PHOTO_PATH)
}
```

**How I am getting the ARG_PHOTO_PATH is explained below**

```
  companion object {
    const val ARG_PHOTO_PATH: String = "ARG_PHOTO_PATH"

    fun newInstance(photoPath: String): DisplayMyFragment {
        val args = Bundle()
        args.putString(ARG_PHOTO_PATH, photoPath)

        val fragment = DisplayMyFragment ()
        fragment.arguments = args
        return fragment
    }
}
```

Till here everything is normal there is no issue working with the above mentioned code , the issue of getting the null value for the bitmap is with some specific device link Samsung galaxy OS version 7

PhotoPath looks like this ---

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myappname.test/files/Pictures/jpg_20201015_131118_8335683392171736788.jpg
```

So my prob is why some device return bitmap null when I convert my image into bitmap and why others devices works fine and return the bitmap ?
Does this is related to the image size, if yes I am not getting any out of memory exception logs in my stack trace.
So I am not sure if this is memory issue.

Stack trace

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath) must not be null
com.myappname.test.DisplayMyFragment.onStart (DisplayMyFragment.kt:62)
androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart (Fragment.java:2730)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start (FragmentStateManager.java:365)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1194)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1356)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState (FragmentManager.java:1434)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1497)
androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps (BackStackRecord.java:447)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps (FragmentManager.java:2169)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether (FragmentManager.java:1992)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute (FragmentManager.java:1947)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions (FragmentManager.java:1849)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange (FragmentManager.java:2629)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchResume (FragmentManager.java:2589)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume (FragmentController.java:269)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments (FragmentActivity.java:478)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume (FragmentActivity.java:467)
androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume (AppCompatActivity.java:195)
android.app.Activity.performResume (Activity.java:7112)
android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3768)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3832)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2994)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4915)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21 (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1637)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6682)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Unclear if the obtained bitmap is null or something else. When is null thrown? By which statement?  Post the stack trace.

Comment: @blackapps added stack trace

Comment: @blackapps null is returned by BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath) this code photoPath null check is already there so no issue with the photoPath it has the value.

Comment: So your bitmap is just null. Then why do you say that null is thrown? Even the device throws null?  decodeFile just returned null.

Comment: Yes bitmap is null my bad I will update the description @blackapps

Comment: Function decodeFile will return null if the bitmap would become to big for available memory. Test it out on those devices with smaller pictures.

Comment: @blackapps its the issue with the end users devices which I do not have.

Comment: If the illegal state exception is thrown -or if null is returned- you could try to decode the file again but now with rescaling/resizing with a factor 8 or so. Then less memory is needed.

Comment: The `BitmapFactory` API is not great. It tends to return `null` for any problem. It is not limited to being out of memory -- the image file could be corrupt, for example. "I am clicking an picture direct from the camera" -- if, by this, you mean that you are using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` (and `FileProvider`), bear in mind that camera apps are very buggy, and so there may not be a valid image at that path to use.

Comment: @CommonsWare So what is the other way around how we can achieve this ?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know what "this" is. If "this" is "take a photo with a camera, with better reliability than `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`", use a library and take a photo from within your app. Jetpack's CameraX will be the long-term solution, but it is still in alpha/beta form. Other libraries include CameraKit-Android and Fotoapparat.